# how can I traverse dataframe without nested for loop?

Tags: pandas

How can I traverse data frame in pandas without nesting for loop?

My code is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],columns=['a','b','c'])
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO, please provide a [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) reproducible example. Also Kindly read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you would want to try this for traversing every row and every column.

```
print([df.loc[row, col] for row in df.index for col in df.columns])
```

This outputs:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is faster:

```
[i for i in df.values.reshape((df.shape[0]*df.shape[1]))]
```

`%%timeit` gave `8.35 µs ± 137 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)`

Comment: It is amazingly faster (9x faster.) Thank you for showing us an alternative way to improve the code.

Comment: I found something interesting. When I use numpy.ravel(), it can save another 30% of time.   `[i for i in df.values.ravel()]`

Comment: @Amy Chou, great solution!